# Can't add git submodule when worktree is a parent directory

Tags: git, version-control, git-submodules, dotfiles

I’m keeping track of my dotfiles with a git repository under `$HOME/.dotfiles` which is configured to track files in `$HOME` (I used `git config core.worktree "../../"`).

This method works fine as long as regular files are concerned, but it fails when I try to add a submodule. Eg:

```
~/.dotfiles $ git submodule add git@github.com:ardagnir/vimbed.git ../../.vim/bundle/vimbed/
fatal: Not a git repository (or any parent up to mount point /home)       
Stopping at filesystem boundary (GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM not set).
```

I also tried `../.vim/...` and `$HOME/.vim/...`.

Is it possible to add a submodule when `core.worktree` is set to a parent of the repo’s default directory? If so, how what command should I use?

Answer (score 0):

Why would you like to track your entire $HOME directory? It would be more reasonable to maintain all dotfiles in your `.dotfiles` folder/repo and then symlink those files to your home, e.g. create a folder `$HOME/.dotfiles/vim` with your config and submodule(s) and then link it to `$HOME/.vim`

You could also easily use a setup script for your dotfiles, that backs up your previous config and then links your dotfiles into `$HOME`.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried with `git submodule`, but for `git stash` setting the environment variable `$GIT_DIR` or using argument `--git-dir` works.  For example, `git --git-dir=./.git stash` (seems silly this is even necessary).

See:
https://git-scm.com/docs/git.html or
https://stackoverflow.com/posts/6392941/edit

Answer (score 0):

**git submodules DO NOT follow `core.worktree` settings** — try:

```
git --git-dir="$HOME/dotfiles" --work-tree="$HOME"
```